# Hough line detection in android using openCV

Tags: android, opencv, image-processing, hough-transform

My mRgba object has dimensions 0X0 so it doesn't return any lines on the picture 
 at all.I guess it is empty. What is the problem in the code? Is there a way to show lines just on 
the black background?

Here is the code

```
    mat = new Mat();
    edges = new Mat();
    Size kernel = new Size(5, 5);
    Mat gauss = new Mat();
    Mat mRgba = new Mat(612,816, CvType.CV_8UC1);
    Mat lines = new Mat(612,816, CvType.CV_8UC1);
    binary_image = new Mat();
    Utils.bitmapToMat(bitmap, mat);
    Imgproc.GaussianBlur(mat, gauss, kernel, 10000, 10000);
    Imgproc.Canny(gauss, edges, 50, 90);
    Imgproc.threshold(edges, binary_image, 0, 255, Imgproc.THRESH_BINARY_INV);

    int threshold = 50;
    int minLineSize = 20;
    int lineGap = 20;

    Imgproc.HoughLinesP(binary_image, lines, 1, Math.PI / 180,threshold,minLineSize,lineGap);



    for (int x = 0; x < lines.cols(); x++) {
        double[] vec = lines.get(0, x);
        double x1 = vec[0],
                y1 = vec[1],
                x2 = vec[2],
                y2 = vec[3];
        Point start = new Point(x1, y1);
        Point end = new Point(x2, y2);

        Core.line(mRgba, start, end, new Scalar(255, 0, 0), 3);

    }

    Bitmap bmp = Bitmap.createBitmap(mRgba.cols(), mRgba.rows(), Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);

    Utils.matToBitmap(mRgba, bmp);
        bitmap=bmp;
```

EDIT: The problem has been solved by removing GaussianBlur and threshold methods

```
    mat = new Mat();
    edges = new Mat();      
    Mat mRgba = new Mat(612,816, CvType.CV_8UC1);
    Mat lines = new Mat();

    Utils.bitmapToMat(bitmap, mat);

    Imgproc.Canny(mat, edges, 50, 90);


    int threshold = 50;
    int minLineSize = 20;
    int lineGap = 20;

    Imgproc.HoughLinesP(edges, lines, 1, Math.PI / 180,threshold,minLineSize,lineGap);



    for (int x = 0; x < lines.cols(); x++) {
        double[] vec = lines.get(0, x);
        double x1 = vec[0],
                y1 = vec[1],
                x2 = vec[2],
                y2 = vec[3];
        Point start = new Point(x1, y1);
        Point end = new Point(x2, y2);

        Core.line(mRgba, start, end, new Scalar(255, 0, 0), 3);

    }

    Bitmap bmp = Bitmap.createBitmap(mRgba.cols(), mRgba.rows(), Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);

    Utils.matToBitmap(mRgba, bmp);
        bitmap=bmp;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. You are not specifying a size for `mRgba` when you are creating it, it should has the same size with the image that you are trying to find lines.
2. You should check `lines` object, to see if you are able to find lines or
   not. You can understand it by checking `mRgba`.
3. This doesn't seem to be the whole code, there is no image loading here. It might be better for you to share whole code and an example image as well.

Comment: here  Utils.bitmapToMat(bitmap, mat); I'm loading an image from camera and it is absolutely fine and visible during debugging. How do I set size of a Mat object?

Comment: @marti6addams I didn't say that there is a problem about loading image, I said it is missing here. For your question, please read some documentation. Here: http://docs.opencv.org/2.4.11/modules/core/doc/basic_structures.html#mat-mat

Comment: @marti6addams and you can understand if you are finding the lines or not as I sad in point 2, without visualization, but still visualization is always nice.

Comment: taken image: http://s28.postimg.org/tthbv4hod/1449154355980.jpg
result: http://s28.postimg.org/8ijrquzjx/Screenshot_2015_12_03_15_53_15.png

Comment: @marti6addams Show `gauss`, `edges`, and `image_binary` also. And please update the code with the latest changes.

Comment: gauss: http://s18.postimg.org/6tkxb982h/Screenshot_2015_12_03_16_09_34.png

edges: http://s18.postimg.org/6fjlbnnyx/Screenshot_2015_12_03_16_12_15.png

binary:http://s18.postimg.org/sq7gbml95/Screenshot_2015_12_03_16_14_26.png

taken from a bit different angles, but of course the same ceiling :) And the funniest thing is that resulting aRgba from the link above is the same despite the thing I'm taking picture of.

Comment: @marti6addams can you also print the whole content of `lines` object? What is the size of `lines` object?

Comment: @marti6addams please put your whole code in a single block.

Comment: this is the lines object 
Mat [ 612*816*CV_8UC1, isCont=true, isSubmat=false, nativeObj=0x51b3a358, dataAddr=0x542b2010 ]

Comment: @marti6addams this is not what I was asking, but still it should not be like this, since it just contains coordinates of lines, it should be array of vectors. Please change this line `Mat lines = new Mat(612,816, CvType.CV_8UC1);` as this `Mat lines = new Mat();` I've told to set size for `mRgba` not `lines`. It is an output of `Imgproc.HoughLinesP` function.

Comment: @marti6addams also try running `Imgproc.HoughLinesP` on `edges` instead of `image_binary`.

Comment: I changed to Mat lines = new Mat(); and the result was the same. In case of running on edges the resulting picture is just black

Comment: @marti6addams what is the size of `lines` now? You need to check it after the hough lines function runs.

Comment: size is I/lines: 906x1

Comment: @marti6addams what is `lines.cols()`, 913, if so, you are finding too many lines, play with the parameters (e.g. increase `threshold` and `minLineSize` to 80 and 30 respectively).